# Let $E$ a vector normed space with $\dim (E)\ge 2$. Prove that $E\setminus\{0\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

> Let $E$ a vector normed space with $\dim (E)\ge 2$. Prove that $E\setminus\{0\}$ is connected.

I think I have a counterexample. Let the vector space $\Bbb Q^2$ with any $p$-norm. Then observe that the sets $\Bbb Q\times ((-\infty,\sqrt 2)\cap\Bbb Q)$ and $\Bbb Q\times ((\sqrt 2,\infty)\cap\Bbb Q)$ are open and disjoint (is easy to check that any point of these subsets is an interior point and it union is $\Bbb Q^2$).

Now, the set $\Big(\Bbb Q\times ((-\infty,\sqrt 2)\cap\Bbb Q)\Big)\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is still open because it is the intersection of open sets. Then the set $\Bbb Q^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is not connected.

This is correct?

Comment: They probably mean to take the ground field to be connected.

Comment: A normed vector space is always a vector space over $ \mathbb R$ or $ \mathbb C$.

Comment: @Fred why? I dont think so. The example above is a normed vector space over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: To me normed spaces are by default over real or complex numbers.